# Killing child processes, and getting child processes pid without psutil or subprocess

Tags: python, linux, process, pid

I'm encountering a lot of problems with this, I want to kill all my child processes without destroying my own process OR kill all the processes of some group OR get all the child processes PID... and all of this WITHOUT using either `subprocess` or `psutil` library in python anyone has any idea how

Comment: How are you launching the child processes? You can always just keep track of them in a list and then call `process.terminate()` or similar to kill them. The lower level API is to use [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill) but this requires you to know the pid and AFAIK the standard library does *not* include any functionality that allows you to search for processes by pid. So if you don't want to use psutil you can always reimplement part of it on your own...

Comment: why do you want to deprive yourself of the use of the packages that work best?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It is not available at my work of enviroment, and not in terms of can't Install, I'm just forbidden to use this library, I cant really explain it, anyways I would like to learn how it is done without those libraries It is more of a learning project

Comment: subprocess is a standard library, installed with the python software. At least use it, and we can help you with the other part.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot access those libraries, you can use `os` if push comes to shove.
For example:

```
my_pid = os.popen('ps --no-headers -C name_of_process').read(5)
if my_pid != "":
    my_pid = int(my_pid)
    os.kill(my_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

'name_of_process' would be the name of your executable
You might also want to look further at the commands `ps` and `pkill`.
Note: I am assuming you are using a Linux OS